# How to use setProgressDrawable() correctly?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am having problem with setting a new Drawable to my ProgressBar.

If I use the setProgressDrawable() inside onCreate() method it works great. But when I try to call the same method inside a Handler post callback it doesn't work and the progressbar disapears.

Can someone explain this behaviour? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Usually, you modify progress via `setProgress()`. Replacing the `Drawable` outright is unusual, even more odd to do it from a `Handler` after the bar is already rendered. What are you attempting to achieve here?

Comment: I want to change color of the progresbar when the value has reached a certain value.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I currently have the same issue (over a year later).  Is this just one big nasty bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bumped into this problem myself and I managed to get it working :)

I used the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to handle the background tasks/threads, but the idea should be the same as using `Runnable/Handler` (though `AsyncTask` does feel nicer imo).

So, this is what I did... put `setContentView(R.layout.my_screen);` in the `onPostExecute` method! (ie. instead of the `onCreate` method)

So the code looks something like this:

```
public class MyScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.my_screen); !!! Don't setContentView here... (see bottom)

    new MySpecialTask().execute();
}

private int somethingThatTakesALongTime() {
    int result;
    // blah blah blah
    return result;
}

private void updateTheUiWithResult(int result) {
    // Some code that changes the UI
    // For exampe:
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    myTextView.setText("Result is: " + result);

    ProgressBar anyProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.custom_progressbar);
    anyProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_style));
    anyProgressBar.setMax(100);
    anyProgressBar.setProgress(result);       
}

private class MySpecialTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyScreen.this, "", "Calculating...\nPlease wait...", true);
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return somethingThatTakesALongTime();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.my_screen); // setContent view here... then it works...
        updateTheUiWithResult(result);
    }
}
}
```

To be honest, why you need to call `setContentView` in `onPostExecute` I have no idea... but doing so means you can set custom styles for your progress bars (and they don't disappear on you!)

Comment: That's because `onPostExecute` is run in the same thread as the UI, while `doInBackground` is run in a background thread, which can't draw directly to the UI. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 16):

```
downloadingBar.setProgress(0); 

Drawable progressDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.download_progressbar_pause_bg);

progressDrawable.setBounds(downloadingBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds()); 

downloadingBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable); 

downloadingBar.setProgress(mCurrentPercent);
```

1. First you should reset the progress to zero
2. Set the progress drawable bounds
3. Set new progress drawable
4. Set new progress

Comment: It seems to work! (I skipped the bounds thing, because the method doesn't even exist in `ProgressBar`). Is this hack documented anywhere?

Comment: getDrawable() is deprecated now 
updated API 
    
    >> Drawable progressDrawable =ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable. download_progressbar_pause_bg);

Comment: thanks, lost some time on this
http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/554/facepalm.jpg

Comment: @ThinkDeep i saw the faceicon. what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you put the code in a thread which is not main thread.
If you want to work with the UI, you must do that in the main thread :)

Comment: It is in a thread. But I use Handler.post(new Runnable() so the operation will be handled by the UI thread. It is working great to update progressbar value. (but not to change the drawable)

Comment: Just my experience, if some view in activity like dialogs (maybe ProgressBar the same) are displayed once, you can not change them any more.
Like: you create a AlertDialog in the onCreateDialog method that does not contain a message. Then, in the onPrepareDialog method, you set the message --> the message will not be display. Sth like cache, as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but in my case it is due to the use of Drawable.mutate() method. When i removed that method it started working fine. I also noticed that this issue exist below api level-21(lollipop).