# Change ProgressBar color in RemoteViews on Android 11 devices

Tags: android, colors, android-progressbar, android-remoteview

I am trying to change the colors of the ProgressBar created with shapes in RemoteViews. It works great on my phone, but on an Android 11 device   the ProgressBar colors don't change. **The problem occurs on Pixel 4xl with Android 11.**

To achieve this I am using reflection API as Oleksandr Albul is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930384/6416627). I using  PreferenceScreen with [ColorPicker](https://github.com/martin-stone/hsv-alpha-color-picker-android) made by Martin Stone

What I want to get:
[the effect I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Mm6.jpg)

What do i get on Android 11 device:
Blue and light gray are set in defaultValue
[the effect I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdc2C.png)

My codes:

Widget layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/widget_background" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget_frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/widget_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="1440"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/widget_circle_shape" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_timeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
           android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/progressbar_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

ProgressBar shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20"
            android:useLevel="false"
            >

            <solid android:color="@color/progressbar_grey" />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20"
                android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

                <solid android:color="@color/progressbar_blue" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Widget Activity:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "updateWidget called");
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeUpdateService.class);
    intent.setAction(TimeUpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_timeText, pendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_progressBar, pendingIntent);

    int currentTime = TimeUtils.getCurrentTime(context);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_timeText, String.valueOf(currentTime));
    remoteViews.setProgressBar(R.id.widget_progressBar, 1440, currentTime, false);


    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(PrefrenceKey.SHOW_BACKGROUND_SHAPE, true)) {
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setVisibility", View.VISIBLE);

        int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(PrefrenceKey.WIDGET_BACKGROUND_COLOR, R.color.progressbar_grey);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setColorFilter", color);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setAlpha", Color.alpha(color));

    } else {
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setVisibility", View.GONE);
    }

    //WIDGET PROGRESSBAR PRIMARY COLOR
    Method setTintColor = null;
    try {
        setTintColor = RemoteViews.class.getMethod("setProgressTintList", int.class, ColorStateList.class);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (setTintColor != null) {
        try {
            int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(PrefrenceKey.WIDGET_PRIMARY_PROGRESSBAR_COLOR, R.color.progressbar_blue);
            setTintColor.invoke(remoteViews, R.id.widget_progressBar, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //WIDGET SECONDARY PROGRESSBAR COLOR
    Method setTintBackgroundColor = null;
    try {
        setTintBackgroundColor = RemoteViews.class.getMethod("setProgressBackgroundTintList", int.class, ColorStateList.class);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (setTintBackgroundColor != null) {
        try {
            int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(PrefrenceKey.WIDGET_SECONDARY_PROGRESSBAR_COLOR, R.color.progressbar_grey);
            setTintBackgroundColor.invoke(remoteViews, R.id.widget_progressBar, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    //WIDGET TEXT COLOR
    int textColor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(PrefrenceKey.WIDGET_TEXT_COLOR, R.color.progressbar_blue);
    remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_timeText, textColor);

    //WIDGET TEXT SIZE
    int textSize = Integer.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(PrefrenceKey.WIDGET_TEXT_SIZE, "20"));
    remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.widget_timeText, COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
    Log.d(TAG, "widget text size" + textSize);


    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);


}
```

I don't have Logcat from Android 11 device.

Do you have an idea how to figure it out?